# Validating app before submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have created an app record in iTunes connect for my app. But due to some keychain private key mismatch problems i was not able to upload its binary. That time its status was ‘Preparing to upload'. So i created new appid, distribution certificate and all for the same app and tried to archive and validate from Xcode. Archiving was successful but while validating it shows the name of the first app i set in itues and gives an error notification ’The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value. If you want to change your bundle identifier you will need to create a new application in iTunes connect’. So i tried to delete that first record from iTunes . But i can’t.

Will somebody help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your target at your "Bundle Identifier".  It's the first option in the "General" tab.  It should be something like `com.company_name.application_name`.  This must match what's set up in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload a valid binary with a BundleID you can not change it anymore.

[image]

My guess is that you did just that, so now you will need to register a new App complete with a different name if you want to use a different BundleID.